# Printer interacting in web application use javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, printing, applet

In my web application I would like to manage our printers (list all printers, check if print exist...), in order to associate each printer with the specific page.
To do this, is it possible to use java-script, jquery or any js library? Or I should use client application like applet, flex, flash...? Because java-script can't read external machine related to machine...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with pure JavaScript. An ActiveX control could work, but you would have to ensure they are on IE, Chrome and Firefox do not support ActiveX by default. And since Chrome and Firefox as of 8/5/2014 have ~70% market share, banking on the user being on IE is a really bad idea. Especially, if the site is external facing.